# how to sum two numbers in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**what is the solution of this by  python 3 ?**

> Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.
>   You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Example:

```
Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,
Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].
```

Comment: use combinations to combine elements together and find the sum

Comment: Agreed. @Jean-FrançoisFabre Python only knows to do what you tell it to do. I'm unaware of such a combination search unless you define it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider reading this documentation: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: @Michael: `itertools.combinations` taken 2 at a time without replacement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `itertools.combinations` which combines the elements of your list into non-repeated couples, and check if the sum matches. If it does, print the positions of the terms:

```
import itertools

integer_array = [2, 8, 4, 7, 9, 5, 1]
target = 10
for numbers in itertools.combinations(integer_array,2):
    if sum(numbers) == target:
        print([integer_array.index(number) for number in numbers])
```

Comment: why you used  itertools.combinations(lst,2) ?

Comment: to generate non-repeating couples, like asked.

Comment: on test case: list = [3,3], target = 6, your code is returning index [0,0], but the ans will be [0,1].

Comment: @HasanShovon - ```itertools.combinations(lst,2)``` is going to return the indices of all combinations of 2 numbers from the array ```lst``` that sum up to the target. If you change 2 to 3, ```itertools.combinations(lst,3)``` is going to return the indices of all combinations of 3 numbers from the array ```lst``` that sum up to the target.

Answer (score 6):

This function iterates through all the numbers in the list and finds the sum with other numbers. If the sum is equal to the target, it returns the indices

```
def indices_sum(nums,target):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(nums)):
            if nums[i]+nums[j] == target: return(i,j)
```

Answer (score 4):

The main problem with solutions testing all possible couples (with imbricated loops or `itertools.combinations`) is that that are O(n^2), as you basically test all possible combinations of two elements among n (there are n*(n-1)/2 such combinations) until you find a valid one.

When n is large, you will need a more efficient algorithm. One possibility is to first sort the list (this is O(n * log(n))), finding the solution can then be done directly in O(n), which gives you a solution in O(n * log(n)).

---

We sort the list first, then add the first (smallest) and last (greatest) values. If the sum is too large, we can remove the largest value. If it's too small, we remove the smallest one, until we reach the exact sum.

We can use a [collection.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-objects) to efficiently remove values at any end of the list.

In order to retrieve the indices, we keep them besides the values in tuples.

```
from collections import deque


def find_target(values, target):

    dq = deque(sorted([(val, idx) for idx, val in enumerate(values)]))

    while True:
        if len(dq) < 2:
            raise ValueError('No match found')

        s =  dq[0][0] + dq[-1][0]

        if s > target:
            dq.pop()
        elif s < target:
            dq.popleft()  
        else:
            break
    return dq[0], dq[-1]



values = [23, 5, 55, 11, 2, 12, 26, 16]
target = 27

sol = find_target(values, target)

print(sol)
# ((11, 3), (16, 7))
# 11 + 16 == 27, indices 3 and 7

print(sol[0][1], sol[1][1])
# 3 7
```

Answer (score 4):

We can do the following:

```
numbers = [2, 7, 11, 15]
target =9
for x in numbers:
    for y in numbers:
        if x+y==target:
            print(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Either of following approaches can be used to finding two numbers numbers in a list that add up to a given target value:

`number_range = [1184.27, 1283.89, 3987.02, 6012.98, 5678.75, 9897.77]`

`target = 10000`

**1. Using for loop:**

`for a in number_range:`
    `for b in number_range[number_range.index(a):]:`
       `if a + b == target:`
           `print(a,b)`

*Output:

3987.02 6012.98*

**2. Using itertools.combinations**

**itertools.combinations(iterable, r)**

This approach combines the list items into unique groups of r (here 2), and check if the sum matches the target.

`import itertools`

`for numbers in itertools.combinations(number_range,2):`
    `if sum(numbers) == target:`
        `print(numbers)`

*Output:  

(3987.02, 6012.98)*

Comment: The question is to find the indices of the numbers, and not the numbers themselves. May be you can improve your solution by fetching the index of the numbers that give the solution

Answer (score 0):

This question has 2 parts:

1. Retrieving the 2 items in a list which equate to the target
2. Retrieving their index value

   def get_index_for_target(nums, target):

   ```
   for x in nums:
       for y in nums:
           if x + y == target:
               return (nums.index(x), nums.index(y))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For each entry in the list, check whether there's any other numbers in the list after that number that add up to the target. Since a+b = target is equivalent to b = target - a, you can just take each element, look at all the numbers after that element, and check whether they are target - element. If so, return the indices.

```
for index,num in  enumerate(nums):
    if target-num in nums[index+1:]:
        return(index, nums.index(target-num))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use to pointers, at the beginning and at the end of the list to check each index by the sum of the two numbers, looping once.

```
def sumOfTwo(array, target):
    i = 0
    j = len(array) - 1
    while i < j:
      add = array[i] + array[j]
      if add == target:
        return True
      elif add < target:
        i += 1
      else:
        j -= 1
    return False 

input -> [1, 2, 3, 4] -> target: 6

 i->    <-j
[1][2][3][4]  if i + j = target return True 
              if i + j < target increase i
              else decrease j
```

***Note:*** In a edge case, a guard of check before the loop, in case: target is a negative value, list is empty, target is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
def indices_sum(nums,target):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(nums)):
            if nums[i]+nums[j] == target: 
                print(nums[i],nums[j])
nums=[1,2,3,4,5]
target=5
indices_sum(nums,target)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please explain how your code answers the specific question being asked. See How to Answer
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer