# How can I optimize my Two Sums code in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm attempting the first problem on leetcode and my code passes the first 19 tests but fails due to a time exceeded failure on the last test. This is what I have so far:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        k = 0
        n = len(nums)-1
        temp = []
        for x in range(k,n):
            for y in range(k+1,n+1):
                if (nums[x]+nums[y] == target) and (x < y):
                    temp.append(x)
                    temp.append(y)
                    break
        return temp
```

Please let me know if you have any information that you think could potentially help me. 
For those of you unfamiliar with the two sums problem. Here it is:

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Example:

```
Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1]
```

I'm asking about the specifics about how to optimize MY code, not have other people write the code for me. Afterall, memorizing code won't do me any good if I don't know how to do it myself with my own thought processes. I'm asking for advice.

Comment: Personally, I'm not sure why you need the second for loop, and why you need (x<y), when it is in your program that x<y. So please post the problem. Can your second for loop be ignored by using - 
if (nums[x] + nums[x+1] == target) and (x<x+1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sum two number in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49761846/how-to-sum-two-number-in-a-list)

Comment: I'm asking how to optimize my code, not copy someone else's. The other post is simply other people writing code for the problem.

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: @ClassicSchmosby you're welcome - note: I've also provided some guidance at the bottom of my answer below that may provide you what you need.

Comment: The main problem with your solution and the ones based on `itertools.combinations` is that that are O(n^2), as you basically test all possible combinations of two elements among n (there are n*(n-1)/2 combinations) until you find a valid one. When n is large, you will need a more efficient algorithm. One possibility is to first sort the list (this is O(n * log(n))), finding the solution is then only O(n), which gives you a solution in O(n * log(n)) globally. I explained it in more detail in my answer on the duplicate. You'll also find many optimization ideas in the other O(n^2) solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably speed things up a little bit using `itertools`, e.g.:

```
for i, j in it.combinations(range(len(nums)), r=2):
    if nums[i] + nums[j] == target:
        return [i, j]
```

Or alternatively:

```
for (i, x), (j, y) in it.combinations(enumerate(nums), r=2):
    if x+y == target:
        return [i, j]
```

An improvement to your code is in your second loop, to start from `x+1` vs `k+1`, this removes the need for the `and` expression. And just immediately return vs. `.append()` which is relatively expensive. E.g.:

```
n = len(nums)-1
for x in range(0, n):
    for y in range(x+1, n+1):
        if nums[x]+nums[y] == target:
            return [x, y]
```

Loops in this structure is exactly what `itertools.combinations()` does.

Answer (score -1):

Try this shortened version of the thing you are doing, this syntax is called 'list comprehension'

```
 def twoSum(nums, target):
        return [(x,x+1) for x in range(len(nums)-1) if nums[x]+nums[x+1] == target]
```

Here is a reference -

http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Comment: I didn't downvote - but this doesn't answer the OP question as it is any 2 indexes not just 2 consecutive indexes, e.g. if `target = 13` then this returns nothing, when it should return `[0, 2]`. Also this returns a list of tuples, not just 2 indexes in a list.

Comment: No indication in the question that the output needed is a list. When I posted my solution the question wasn't properly defined. There was just code, hence I asked the OP why the second for loop was needed. He stated the full question later. Thanks for not downvoting.